# Bootstrap spacing Utilities v5.1

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I'm reading the documentation on Bootstrap spacing utilities and it is unclear to me how to apply spacing (either margin or padding) to only **ONE** side of an element.

I am using the class `.ps-5` and I would expect that to add padding to either left or right depending on reading direction RTL or LTR,  but it is applying the padding to **BOTH** sides of the element. Screenshot below shows how both padding-left and padding-right are being applied to the element.

What am I missing?

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/spacing/

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code.

Comment: It seems like you are loading both files (LTRand RTL), I suggest you load only the RTL css if page is RTL